# Uploading image to website's folder

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
<form action="galleryimages.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">File name</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"http://abxd.com/images/gallery/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                $query_image="insert into gallery (image) values ('".$_FILES['file']['name']."')";
               mysqli_query($link,$query_image)
                    ?>
```

Actually, i am facing a problem on uploading image in folder from my website....  I have written the code for storing image in a folder and stores it name into the database. The code i write is properly run on localhost but not running on my website ( which is onto the server). Please anyone, help me and tell me... Why this is happened so and what should i do..

Comment: Why did you tag your question with phpmyadmin ?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) function has to be a path on the server, not an URL, such as `/path/to/folder/your_file`.